# File only 15MB - drive.files.insert failed with error: Request Too Large

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, ocr, google-api-js-client

I have a short script to OCR jpg files by converting them to GDOCS. It works fine for JPGs around 5MB. But for a 600dpi scan, where the file size is more like 15MB I get the following error for a single image:

```
5:40:58 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:41:03 PM  Error   
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: Request Too Large
convertJpegToGdoc   @ convertJpegToGdoc.gs:27
```

The relevant line of code is:

```
Drive.Files.insert({title: file.getName(), parents: [{id: dstFolderId}]
                    }
```

I am aware of quotas [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) The error I am getting is **not** one of these. The time shows that the script is not exceeding the 6 mins listed in the docs. BTW I can convert multiple images, each approx 1.5MB, with 24 character JPG file basenames, into gdocs without problems using this script.

The Google Drive API for insert [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert) javascript example suggests, perhaps,  that I may need to upgrade my code to handle larger files. But I am not sure where to start.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Full code:

```
// this function does OCR while copying from ocrSource to ocrTarget
function convertJpegToGdoc() {

var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcFolderId).getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG); 

while (files.hasNext()) { var file = files.next(); 
Drive.Files.insert({title: file.getName(), parents: [{id: dstFolderId}]
                        }, 
    file.getBlob(), {ocr: true}); 

}                         
                         
// this moves files from ocrSource to ocrScriptTrash
// handy for file counting & keeping ocrSource free for next batch of files 
var inputFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcFolderId);
var processedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(trshFolderId);

var files = inputFolder.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.moveTo(processedFolder);
     }                         
   
}
```

Comment: Although I cannot test your image, by using a workaround used when I had the same situation, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful for your image, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I tested your code. No result. No errors. (For a single JPG file 15MB) Using a 5MB JPG I ran my original code and converted the image to a 1KB GDOC. Using this same JPG I tried your code again. No result. No errors. I am going to test different sized JPG files to ascertain the threshold where the OCR fails.

Comment: The only doc that I can find that mentions limits is https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads This ruling may affect other types of file transmission on Google Dive platform. Because I don't consider the functionality of the code (that I am using above) constitutes an "upload"

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I tested your code. No result. No errors. (For a single JPG file 15MB) Using a 5MB JPG I ran my original code and converted the image to a 1KB GDOC. Using this same JPG I tried your code again. No result. No errors. I am going to test different sized JPG files to ascertain the threshold where the OCR fails.`, unfortunately, when I tested my script using my sample image, no error occurs and a new Google Document is created. I apologize for this. In order to correctly `No result. No errors`, can you provide the sample image? By this, I would like to test it.

Comment: Thank you for your continuing interest. I have shared the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hpi1uqnQGP0TJetMLKNsEsmEgkHw776F/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for providing your sample image. When I tested my proposed script using your sample image, I can confirm that a new Google Document is created and the covered texts are included. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate `No result. No errors.`. I think that this is due to my very poor skill. I have to apologize for my very poor skill. In order to correctly replicate your `No result. No errors.`, can you provide your current script for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to try to replicate your situation.

Comment: Sure. https://script.google.com/d/1cyztYffKMA6V5jjjGO4c2X-JE16F4bkqApFwtDE_oMXDIqER0_qdbeow/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't see it. I apologize for this.

Comment: Sorry Tanaike. I was not thinking. Here https://script.google.com/d/1cyztYffKMA6V5jjjGO4c2X-JE16F4bkqApFwtDE_oMXDIqER0_qdbeow/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your current script, I understood the reason for your current issue. So, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 3):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert a JPEG to Google Doucment as OCR using Drive API.

When I saw your question, I remembered that I experienced the same situation as you. At that time, even when the resumable upload is used, the same error of `Request Too Large` couldn't be removed. For example, as the reason for this issue, I thought the file size, the image size, the resolution of the image, and so on. But I couldn't find a clear reason for this. So, in that case, I used the following workaround.

My workaround is to reduce the image size. By this, the file size and image size can be reduced. By this, I could remove the issue. In this answer, I would like to propose this workaround.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
Drive.Files.insert({title: file.getName(), parents: [{id: dstFolderId}]
                        }, 
    file.getBlob(), {ocr: true}); 

}
```

#### To:

```
try {
  Drive.Files.insert({ title: file.getName(), parents: [{ id: dstFolderId }] }, file.getBlob(), { ocr: true });
} catch ({ message }) {
  if (message.includes("Request Too Large")) {
    const link = Drive.Files.get(file.getId()).thumbnailLink.replace(/=s.+/, "=s2000");
    Drive.Files.insert({ title: file.getName(), parents: [{ id: dstFolderId }] }, UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getBlob(), { ocr: true });
  }
}
```

- In this modification, when the error of `Request Too Large` occurs, the image size is reduced by modifying the thumbnail link. In this sample, the horizontal size is 2000 pixels by keeping the aspect ratio.

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that Drive API has already been enabled at Advanced Google services. Please be careful about this.

### Added:

Your script in your question is as follows.

```js
// this function does OCR while copying from ocrSource to ocrTarget
function convertJpegToGdoc() {

var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcFolderId).getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG); 

while (files.hasNext()) { var file = files.next(); 
Drive.Files.insert({title: file.getName(), parents: [{id: dstFolderId}]
                        }, 
    file.getBlob(), {ocr: true}); 

}                         
                         
// this moves files from ocrSource to ocrScriptTrash
// handy for file counting & keeping ocrSource free for next batch of files 
var inputFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcFolderId);
var processedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(trshFolderId);

var files = inputFolder.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.moveTo(processedFolder);
     }                         
   
}
```

In my answer, I proposed the following modification.

#### From:

```
Drive.Files.insert({title: file.getName(), parents: [{id: dstFolderId}]
                        }, 
    file.getBlob(), {ocr: true}); 

}
```

#### To:

```
try {
  Drive.Files.insert({ title: file.getName(), parents: [{ id: dstFolderId }] }, file.getBlob(), { ocr: true });
} catch ({ message }) {
  if (message.includes("Request Too Large")) {
    const link = Drive.Files.get(file.getId()).thumbnailLink.replace(/=s.+/, "=s2000");
    Drive.Files.insert({ title: file.getName(), parents: [{ id: dstFolderId }] }, UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getBlob(), { ocr: true });
  }
}
```

But, when I saw your current script, your current script is as follows.

```js
// convertJpegToGdoc.js - script converts .jpg to .gdoc files
// Google Script Project - ocrConvert  https://script.google.com/home/projects/1sDHfmK4H19gaLxxtXeYv8q7dql5LzoIUHto-OlDBofdsU2RyAn_1zbcr/edit
// clasp location C:\Users\david\Google Drive\ocrRollConversion

// Begin with empty folders (see below) 
// Transfer a set of Electoral Roll .JPG from storage into ocrSource folder
// Running this script performs OCR conversions on the .JPG files
// .JPG files are converted to .GDOC & stored in ocrTarget
// The .JPG ocrSource files are transferred to ocrScriptTrash leaving the ocrSource folder empty if all goes well

// Uses Google Drive root folders (~\Google Drive\)
// 1. ocrSource
// 2. ocrTarget 
// 3. ocrScriptTrash

// to check Id value open folder in Google Drive then examine URL
let srcFolderId = "###"; //ocrSource   
let dstFolderId = "###"; //ocrTarget  
let trshFolderId = "###"; //ocrScriptTrash

// this function does OCR while copying from ocrSource to ocrTarget (adjusted try/catch for larger jpgs)
function convertJpegToGdocRev1() {

var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcFolderId).getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG); 

try {
    Drive.Files.insert({ title: file.getName(), parents: [{ id: dstFolderId }] }, file.getBlob(), { ocr: true });
  } catch ({ message }) {
    if (message.includes("Request Too Large")) {
      const link = Drive.Files.get(file.getId()).thumbnailLink.replace(/=s.+/, "=s2000");
      Drive.Files.insert({ title: file.getName(), parents: [{ id: dstFolderId }] }, UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getBlob(), { ocr: true });
    }
  }                       
                         
// this moves files from ocrSource to ocrScriptTrash
// handy for file counting & keeping ocrSource free for next batch of files 
var inputFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcFolderId);
var processedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(trshFolderId);

var files = inputFolder.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.moveTo(processedFolder);
     }                         
   
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that you miscopied my proposed answer. In your current script, `var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcFolderId).getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);` is not used. And, when try-catch is not used, an error occurs. But, because of try-catch, when you run the script, `No result. No errors` occurs. I think that the reason for your current issue of `No result. No errors` is due to this.

In order to use my proposed modification, please correctly copy and paste the script. By this, the modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

**Please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.**

```js
let srcFolderId = "###"; //ocrSource   
let dstFolderId = "###"; //ocrTarget  
let trshFolderId = "###"; //ocrScriptTrash

function convertJpegToGdocRev1() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcFolderId).getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var name = file.getName();
    console.log(name) // You can see the file name at the log.
    try {
      Drive.Files.insert({ title: name, parents: [{ id: dstFolderId }] }, file.getBlob(), { ocr: true });
    } catch ({ message }) {
      if (message.includes("Request Too Large")) {
        const link = Drive.Files.get(file.getId()).thumbnailLink.replace(/=s.+/, "=s2000");
        Drive.Files.insert({ title: file.getName(), parents: [{ id: dstFolderId }] }, UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getBlob(), { ocr: true });
      }
    }
  }
  var inputFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcFolderId);
  var processedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(trshFolderId);
  var files = inputFolder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.moveTo(processedFolder);
  }
}
```

Comment: The lines `while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var name = file.getName();
    console.log(name) // You can see the file name at the log.` are not in your first modification.

Comment: I ran your modified script and got `Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp`

Comment: I have to say. Using a workaround to reduce the file size for an OCR conversion is a compromise not a solution.

Comment: @Dave Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for the inconvenience. About `The lines while (files.hasNext()) {     var file = files.next();     var name = file.getName();     console.log(name) // You can see the file name at the log. are not in your first modification.`, unfortunately, in my answer, `while` is not modified from your showing script. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Dave About `I ran your modified script and got Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp`, when I tested the bottom scriptm no error occurs. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. I deeply apologize that when I tested my script, no error occurs. I think that this is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again.

Comment: @Dave About `I have to say. Using a workaround to reduce the file size for an OCR conversion is a compromise not a solution. –`, I really apologize that I proposed a workaround. I think that this is due to my very poor skill. I deeply apologize for my very poor skill again. I have to study more.

Comment: @Dave I think that your 1st issue of `No result. No errors.` and your 2nd issue of `Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp` are due to my very poor skill. I really apologize for my very poor skill again.